# SSM agent fails working on EC2 post IDMSV2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I'm on a Windows server. I had to relaunch an instance from a snapshot of another instance that might have been in a different availability zone. One other change is that I've enabled imdsv2 on the EC2 by updating the launch configuration earlier while creating the new instance.

The [SSM Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent.html) on this instance is failing with this error -

> caused by: Get "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers) 
> 2023-03-08 05:29:34 ERROR [newAgentIdentityInner @ identity_selector.go.99] Agent failed to assume any identity 
> 2023-03-08 05:29:34 ERROR [NewAgentIdentity @ identity_selector.go.112] failed to find identity, retrying: failed to find agent identity 
> 2023-03-08 05:29:41 ERROR [NewEC2Identity @ ec2_identity.go.281] [EC2Identity] failed to get identity instance id. Error: RequestError: send request failed

I don't have access to the EC2 on the CLI, so I cannot use the `ec2 describe-instance` CLI command mentioned in [Use SSM Agent logs to troubleshoot issues in your managed instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ssm-agent-logs/) to check if instance metadata is enabled. I know it was. And there isn't any proxy required.

This [issue](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ssm-agent/issues/348) on GitHub is somewhat similar to mine but I don't understand what I need to do to fix this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually found my answer. As mentioned in [this video by Amazon](https://youtu.be/DEkrcNkF-4Q), the routes for 169.254.169.254 were pointing to the incorrect gateway of the different subnet.

This issue was resolved by running `Import-Module C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Module\Ec2Launch.psm1; Add-Routes` on PowerShell as administrator.

Comment: what is the rollback for this in case if things go wrong?

Comment: Restoring from snapshot again. That's the only rollback available.

Comment: I had this error after moving an instance to a different subnet (via create image). This command fixed it for me. Thanks for digging it up.

Comment: Awesome! I dont know why this is not part of the offical docos. Thanks for the share